# How to find $A=UDU^H$ in this case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given  a matrix $A$. I find out it **is normal**. And I compute $\det(A-\lambda)=0$ and find that not all $\lambda_i$ are different, i.e., the eigenvalues are **not distinct**. Thus, I am not sure if the eigenvectors are L.I.

Now, I want find a decomposition $$A=UDU^H$$ but how do I do it? And under what conditions can I do that?

Where

- $D$ is a diagonal matrix
- $^H$ is the hermitian conjucate
- $U$ is unitary matrix.

Comment: What is $U^H$? What is $D$?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick added a list at the end.

Comment: @GitGud it should read "normal" instead of "not normal". edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is normal, you can always find the decomposition $A=UDU^H$.

Assuming you know how to diagonalize a matrix, to find $U$ you simply take any diagonalizing matrix $P$ and apply [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the columns of $P$. The resulting vectors, disposed as the columns of $U$, make $U$unitary.