# Orthogonally diagonalizing a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Can anybody explain how to orthogonally diagonalize the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        9 & \sqrt10  \\
        \sqrt10 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Am I correct in saying the eigenvalues are 10 and -1 and the corresponding eigenvectors are [1,1/sqrt(10)] and [1,-sqrt(10)]

Comment: yes, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+%7B%7B9%2C%E2%88%9A10%7D%2C%7B%E2%88%9A10%2C0%7D%7D and to diagonalize, use a matrix with the eigenvectors and conjugate as $M^{-1}AM$

Comment: You can use the process explained in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/715354/55235) answer.

Comment: here is a [diagonalisation](http://matrixcalc.org/en/#diagonalize%28%7B%7B9,10%5E0%2E5%7D,%7B10%5E0%2E5,0%7D%7D%29) calculator with steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can diagonalize as: $$\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10}$$

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to get Q such that (Q^T)AQ where A is the matrix I gave in the question?

Comment: @gary see git guds answer. Also note that the diagonal entries are exactly the eigenvalues you already calculated ...